# Proof for order of cyclic groups. why does it need to continue?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote, page 57, I have a question regarding the proof of:

**Proposition 5** Let $G$ be a group, $x \in G$.  Let $a \in \mathbb{Z} - \{ 0 \}$. If $|x| = n < \infty$,  $|x^{a}| = \frac{n}{(n,a)}$.

**Proof:** Let $y =x^{a}, (n,a) = d \: and \: write\: n = db, a=dc$.  Note since $d = (n,a)$ $b$ and $c$ are relatively prime $(b,c) = 1$. To establish our prop, we must show $|y| = b$.  Note that $y^{b} = x^{ab} = x^{dcb} = (x^{n})^c = 1^c = 1$

***my note:*** I thought that the proof would end here...since by def of order, $y^{b} =1$ implies $|y| = b$ and we let $y = x^{a}$ so $|x^{a}| = b$ and since we let $n = db$, $b = \frac{n}{d}$ so we have $|x^{a}| = \frac{n}{d}$, which is what we needed to prove.  But the proof in the book goes on.***end my note***

**Proof continuted:** By previous prop applied to $<y>$, we have that $|y|$ divides $b$.  Let $k = |y|$.  Then $x^{ak} = y^{k} = 1$.  So by the same previous prop applied to $<x>$, $n | ak$, or using our substitutions, $db | dck$.  Thus $b | ck$. Since $(b,c) = 1$. we must have that $b |k$. Since $b, k$ are positive ints that divide each other, $b=k$.

***My question:*** Why do we need to continue after my previous note?

Comment: No, $y^b =1$ only implies $|y|$ divides $b$. For example, you know that $(-1)^4 =1$, but also note that $(-1)^2 =1$, and the order of $-1$ is $2$ not $4$ [the group could be $\{1, -1\}$].

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the order of $y$ is the smallest $k$ such that $y^k=e$. So, from the fact that $y^b=e$, all you can deduce is that $\operatorname{ord}y\leqslant b$, not that $\operatorname{ord}y=b$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with minimality! The order of $x$ is the minimal $n$ s.t. $x^n=1$, However, what you just found is one $n$ s.t. $x^n=1$. Hence ones till needs to work through the minimality. as an example: take $1 \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (where we work additively, i.e. $x^n=n*x$)then you have $2k*1=0$, but the order is $2$ since this is the MINIMAL number such that $2*1=0$. in your proof above in this case, you might have found the "order" $16$, but you then need to reduce it to $2$